# Usage of 'it has been' along with 'since' in this context

Tags: grammar, british-english, syntactic-analysis

Is below syntax grammatically and logically correct?

It has been a more than a year since my grandmother's demise.

or I should say

It has been a more than a year to my grandmother's demise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It has been more than a year since my grandmother died

or

> It has been more than a year since my grandmother's demise.